# MVC: How to change URL address in browser based on the AJAX request for the page?

Tags: jquery, actionlink, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have an AJAX request on my MVC page:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link","Index","Page1",new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId= "mainAjax", LoadingElementId="loader", OnComplete="ChangeUrl();" })
```

When clicking on the link, the page is loaded with the correct content, however, `URL` is not changed.

When clicking on the `Link`, the address bar should have `http://localhost:1111/Link` address.

What needs to be done to update the URL with the correct address of the requested page?

Comment: Make it a regular anchor tag instead of an ajax request.  The purpose of ajax is to load content onto the current page *without* navigating away from the page.

Comment: Actually, that was a purpose of having ajax request, so, I refresh the portion of the page without navigating away from it

Comment: You can't change the location bar without a navigation action.  Otherwise scammers would throw up a fake page and make it look like it was google.com or some such.

Comment: I did actually changed it using `window.history.pushState(null, null, url)` That changed the URL string for me. However, when I'm clicking `back` button, I cannot navigate through the histrory

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery binding on click event. for sample So you could add a class attribute to your links as follows;

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link Title", "ActionName", "Controller", new { @class = "menuItems" })
```

The add your click event;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $(".menuItems").click(function() {
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            if (href.indexOf("javascript") >= 0)
                return;
            history.pushState(null, $(this).html, href);
        });
    });
```

you must attend to href parameter that passing to pushState function. this URL argument to pushState should be relative to the current page, or or an absolute URL in your own domain. You can't push state cross-domain - it would be a major security flaw. 
if URL argument is not correct, you get this error "**Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL**".